# Are there any memoization mechanisms in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, react

I am just curious if there are any memoization mechanisms in Lightning Web Components similar to `useMemo` in React.

**What I want to achieve:**
I want to be sure that that all costly calculations are made only when needed, and not on every rerender.

Comment: LWC rerendering (I don't mean initial rendering here) is, from my understanding, smart in that it only rerenders parts of the template that require rerendering due to value changes. Thus, if you store your properties as computed values, rather than as getters that compute on demand, you have immediately provided memoization for yourself. The other point of note is that interaction with the server to cacheable methods (using wires or imperative calls) is cached by the LWC infrastructure to avoid the need to do a server-side call at all while the cache is fresh.

Comment: What do you mean by saying `computed values`? Can you show me an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LWC re-renders parts of the template that require it based on property changes. It also ensures that redundant calls to the server are avoided, when you invoke cacheable imperative or wires, by having a client-side cache built into the LWC infrastructure based on any parameter values and the targeted imperative apex or wire.

A common pattern is to simply ensure that all properties used in the template are pre-computed.

For example, if I have a property, `a`, that is calculated from properties `b` and `c`, and that is used in the component's rendering, I would write my LWC thus:

```
import { LightningElement, api } from "lwc";

export default class Child extends LightningElement {
  // The computed property. Note that this is very simple and simply holds a value
  a;

  // A "private" property used to hold the "b" property value
  _b;

  // A "private" property used to hold the "c" property value
  _c;

  // The "b" API property is implemented with get/set so that when it is set we can calculate "a" from it
  @api get b() {
    return this._b;
  }

  set b(value) {
    this._b = value;
    this.calcA();
  }

  // The "c" API property is implemented with get/set so that when it is set we can calculate "a" from it
  @api get c() {
    return this._c;
  }

  set c(value) {
    this._c = value;
    this.calcA();
  }

  // A function used to calculate "a" when "b" or "c" changes
  calcA() {
    if (this.b && this.c) {
      this.a = this.b * this.c;
    }
  }
}
```

You can find this example on the [playground](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/GwHn7c9AhYJMFh1V1jvd/src/app.js).

Other community members may know better patterns, but this is based on the one we typically apply.